# Sublime. Произвольное выделение фрагментов кода жёлтым цветом

Tags: sublime-text-3

Во время работы (Sublime Text 3.0 Build 3143) программа бессистемно выделяет фрагменты кода жёлтым цветом. Работать не сильно мешает, но немного раздражает. Спрашивал на материнском форуме Sublime, но помощи не дождался. Скриншот прикладываю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо!